# How to test React component method without parameter using Jest?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, jestjs

currently, I am trying to test my app, I am trying to test my components method. So this is my component code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

//Style
const style = {
    box: {
        width: '96%',
        height:120,
        marginLeft: 'auto',
        marginRight: 'auto',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10,
        display:'flex',
    },
    votes: {
        width: '12%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#EEE',
        display:'block',
        textAlign: 'center',
        borderTopLeftRadius:5,
        borderBottomLeftRadius:5
    },
    detail: {
        width: '88%',
        height: '100%',
        backgroundColor: '#DDD',
        borderTopRightRadius:5,
        borderBottomRightRadius:5,
    },
    image: {
        height: '35%',
        width: '35%',
    },
}

//Component of one topic, contains all the button to upvote and downvote. 
export class OneTopic extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //bind all the function
        this.upvotes = this.upvotes.bind(this);
        this.downvotes = this.downvotes.bind(this);
    }

    //function to upvote, will call the function that passed by Topic table(but from App.jsx)
    upvotes() {
        this.props.upvote(this.props.title);
    }

    //funtion to downvote, will call the function that passed by Topic table(but from App.jsx)
    downvotes() {
        this.props.downvote(this.props.title);
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div style={style.box}>
                <div style = {style.votes}>
                    <img src="img/upvote.png" className="vote" style={style.image} alt="upvote" onClick = {this.upvotes}/>
                        <div style={{backgroundColor:'#AAA',padding:3, width: 20, height:20, textAlign:'center', margin:'auto', fontSize:20, marginBottom:4}} >
                            {this.props.vote}
                        </div>
                    <img src="img/downvote.png" className="vote" style={style.image} alt="downvote" onClick={this.downvotes}/>
                </div>
                <div style = {style.detail}>
                    <h2 className="margin">{this.props.title} </h2><hr className="margin" />
                    <p className="margin descrip">{this.props.desc} </p>
                </div>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

please focus one the upvotes function. I tried to test this by using Jest instance, this is my code for testing:

```
it('Child oneTopic is not crashing', () => {
        const wrapper = mount(<oneTopic />);
        wrapper.instance().upvotes();
    });
```

This is the error message :

```
TypeError: wrapper.instance(...).upvotes is not a function
```

Please help me, I prefer not to use snapshot since it looks complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the simulate method.

```
wrapper.find(".vote").first().simulate('click');
```

If you wish to simulate the other function i.e. downVote

```
wrapper.childAt(0).childAt(0).childAt(0).simulate('click');  // upVote
wrapper.childAt(0).childAt(0).childAt(2).simulate('click');  // downVote
```

Or another way would be to give unique ids to the two images & you can access it as ("#upVote") or ("#downVote") instead of (".vote")

Comment: can you please explain to me, how "wrapper.find(".vote").first().simulate('click');"
works at my code and what is .vote? ?

Comment: you have two images with the class "vote" so you need to trigger the click of the first image that calls the "upvotes" method.

Comment: Let me try it first

Comment: Hi Jonah, how can I access the second vote ? is it .second() ?

Comment: Edited the answer

Comment: Hi, I tried using const upvotebutton = wrapper.find('img').at(0) -> which mean upvote image. And the I simulate by using upvotebutton.simulate('click'); and become error.
this is the error message :
TypeError: this.props.upvote is not a function
I think thats because when the upvote image clicked, it will call this.props.upvote which is not a inner function. But other component function. Any idea ?

Comment: you need to mock your functions this.props.upvote and this.props.downvote which are passed onto you component as props

Comment: Can you please guide me ?